# PHP INSERT into table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here is my query. I don't know why it's not running it? Is my syntax wrong?

```
$query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO ps_search_index (id_product, id_word, weight) 
SELECT DISTINCT Product_ID, Product_ID + 5000 'id_word', '1' 
FROM ps_product_part_number 
    WHERE   API != '' AND API IS NOT NULL";
```

Comment: `Product_ID + 5000 'id_word'` is supposed to be what?

Comment: its adding 5000 to the id word , it worked in navi cat i just need it to be in php

Comment: Do you have any errors in the logs?

Comment: It's adding 5000 to the value of Product_ID; but the syntax gives no indication of what it's supposed to be doing with `'id_word'` (other than using `id_word` as a quoted string

Comment: This is the raw sql

INSERT IGNORE INTO ps_search_index (id_product, id_word, weight) 
SELECT DISTINCT Product_ID, Product_ID + 5000 'id_word', '1' 
FROM ps_product_part_number 
 WHERE API != '' AND API IS NOT NULL;

Comment: this is invalid, raw sql

Comment: You can't run two queries in same time, but on the other hand, if you tried to make subquery then wrap it inside brackets

Comment: `INSERT IGNORE INTO ps_search_index (id_product, id_word, weight) 
SELECT DISTINCT Product_ID, Product_ID + 5000 'id_word', '1' 
FROM ps_product_part_number 
 WHERE API != '' AND API IS NOT NULL;
INSERT IGNORE INTO ps_search_word (id_word, id_shop, id_lang, word) 
SELECT DISTINCT Product_ID + 5000 'id_word', '1', '1', API  
FROM ps_product_part_number 
 WHERE API != '' AND API IS NOT NULL;`

Comment: `Product_ID + 5000 'id_word'` still makes no sense

Comment: its taking the product_id adding 5000 and then inserting it in the id_word column

Comment: put a working example in http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: This is what i get when i run it ... [SQL]INSERT IGNORE INTO ps_search_index (id_product, id_word, weight) 
SELECT DISTINCT Product_ID, Product_ID + 5000 'id_word', '1' 
FROM ps_product_part_number 
 WHERE API != '' AND API IS NOT NULL;
Affected rows: 173
Time: 0.016s

[SQL]
INSERT IGNORE INTO ps_search_word (id_word, id_shop, id_lang, word) 
SELECT DISTINCT Product_ID + 5000 'id_word', '1', '1', API  
FROM ps_product_part_number 
 WHERE API != '' AND API IS NOT NULL;
Affected rows: 161
Time: 0.019s

Comment: @phpcfm `Product_ID + 5000 'id_word'` still is not valid SQL. Using this in SQL it would result in an error. Ergo, this is not SQL but some other language if it is really working for you.

Comment: yea because i use it in navicat and it does exactly what i want it to do

Comment: then navcat is either a terrible tool, or magic, as it turns invalid sql in to valid sql

Comment: @phpcfm please tell me if you could take a look at my answer, and whether or not i actually understood wht your problem is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably you mean `Product_ID + 5000 AS  id_word`

Also i would remove the ignore, so you can read any error in the development time.

```
INSERT  INTO ps_search_index (id_product, id_word, weight) 
SELECT DISTINCT Product_ID, Product_ID + 5000 AS  id_word , '1' 
FROM ps_product_part_number 
    WHERE   API != '' AND API IS NOT NULL
```

Also, i think you dont need the `AS  id_word` since the `INSERT...SELECT` syntax will insert the values in the fields in the order you declare it, so you dont need to use an alias, so this will be the same:

```
INSERT  INTO ps_search_index (id_product, id_word, weight) 
SELECT DISTINCT Product_ID, Product_ID + 5000, '1' 
FROM ps_product_part_number 
    WHERE   API != '' AND API IS NOT NULL"
```

Comment: I got it working ... with the same sql i had up top... thank you alot your method made since ! i just went a different route .. my original route

Comment: ok! since the question was confusing, please upvote or accept if the answer solve the problem, even if it is in a different way

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of working INSERT code for the php.

If you want to add 5000 using SQL code, I would strongly recommend that you do it on php before putting it inside the SQL code.

**EDITED**

```
$id_product += 5000;

$query = "INSERT INTO ps_search_index (id_product, id_word, weight) VALUES ('$id_product', '$id_word', '$weight')";
```

Comment: how would i add 5000 to it then ?